# Send broadcast after x seconds when activity finishes

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a snooze button, which works fine but I need the activity to close when snooze is pressed. Here's what I have:

```
public void snoozeClicked(View view){

    MainActivity.ringtone.stop();
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Actions to do after 10 seconds
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            sendBroadcast(myIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 10000);
```

This closes the activity after x seconds, but I need to do it immediately while the intent waits to broadcast even if the activity is closed. How can I do this?

Comment: I don;t quite understand your question. What do you need to do immediately and what do you need to do after 10 seconds?

Comment: Close the activity immediately, send the broadcast in 10 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should schedule a PendingIntent with AlarmManager. That way you can `finish()` the activity immediately and not worry about the Handler.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadtcast(this, 0,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
long triggerTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS;
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, pendingIntent);

finish();
```